# Generating finite lists of primes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, sequence, primes, idioms, induction

There are a lot topics on generating prime numbers in Haskell, but in my opinion, they all rely on '`isPrime`' function, which, if we don't know the primes sequence yet, should look like:

```
isPrime k = if k > 1 then null [ x | x <- [2,3..(div k 2) + 1], k `mod` x == 0]
                     else False
```

(`div` might be replaced with `sqrt`, but still...)

I've tried to construct prime numbers based on 'inductive definition' (assume we have a set of first *n* primes, then *(n+1)th* prime is the least integer such that none of the first *n* primes is a divisor of it). I've tried to do it in the Fibonacci sequence way, which is:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fibs !! n
    where fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

And I ended up with this:

```
-- checking if second number is a divisor of first one
ifDoesn'tDivide :: Int -> Int -> Bool
ifDoesn'tDivide n k 
    | mod n k == 0 = False
    | otherwise    = True

-- generating list which consists of first n prime numbers
firstPrimes :: Int -> [Int]
-- firstPrimes 1  = [2]
firstPrimes n     = take n primes 
    where primes = 2:(tail primes) ++ 
         [head [x | x <- [3,4..], k <- primes, ifDoesn'tDivide x k == True]]
```

But it doesn't work, *stack overflow* when `n >= 2`. Any advice on how to fix it?

*"Haskell can define data structures in terms of themselves in effect creating infinite data structures"*. Those prime numbers and Fibonacci sequences mentioned earlier are specific cases of defining data structures in terms of themselves, and Fibonacci sequence works just fine, but these `primes` doesn't.

Am I missing something, are those two algorithms different in a substantive way?

P.S. So, I think, I'm just looking for most 'Haskellish' way to do that.

Comment: ``ifDoesn'tDivide n k = n`mod`k/=0``. Generally speaking, there's seldom any reason to explicitly mention `True` or `False`. — Anyway, so... _what's your question?_

Comment: It doesn't work. Stack overflow if n>=2. Looking for advice on how to fix it.

Comment: If `primes` is supposed to be an infinite list, then `tail primes` is also an infinite list. Appending something to an infinite list ain't gonna work.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. but we don't know whether it's suppose to be infinite or not, and neither does Haskell. Haskell knows nothing in fact, except that which we told it, with `primes = 2 : tail primes ++ expr`, i.e. that `head primes =: 2` and `tail primes =: tail primes`.

Comment: @WillNess I am not saying anything about what Haskell knows. I am talking about what the programmer thinks. Does the programmer think it should be infinite? If so, then ++ing anything to it is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 9):

You can always use a sieve which is rather elegant in Haskell.

```
primes = sieve [2..]

sieve (p : xs) = p : sieve [ x | x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0 ]
```

So to get the first 10 primes

```
> take 10 primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]
```

Notice that while `isPrime` is not explicitly used the list comprehension ensures that every number on the list must be prime relative to all the primes preceding it, which is to say prime.

<s>This is more efficient and it's at the heart of [Eratosthenes' sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)</s>(Edit).

The code above is the first example in:

- Melissa E. O'Neill, [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Genuine-Sieve-of-Eratosthenes-O%27Neill/ff63a2b396b001d921dc593c4249d74c1b96ec5b)

The paper goes in to much more detail about the efficient implementation of sieves in Haskell and the role of laziness in the computation. Highly recommended!

Comment: I believe I have read that `rem` is more efficient than `mod`, and for positive numbers produces the same result.

Comment: "it's at the heart of Eratosthenes' sieve" no, in all likelihood all he did was *counting*, never *dividing* any numbers. Rev. S. Horsley F.R.S. was *quite adamant* about it, in 1772, when he (re)introduced the sieve of Eratosthenes into modernity. "with little labour" certainly precludes any repeated modulus calculations.

Comment: also, the main drive of that article is to show that that code at the top of this post is *not* the sieve *of Eratosthenes*. then it derives its complexity as being *quadratic* in number of primes produced with it, whereas the true sieve's is just (log log n) above linearithmic.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't mean to abuse the concept. Just tried to emphasize the difference in determining primality. Nonetheless, valid criticism.

Comment: [no criticism, just a correction](http://www.dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html). BTW "This is more efficient" also doesn't make sense to me. more efficient than what? than using the `isPrime` function? it isn't; the sieve code you include is very inefficient (quadratic), which, again, is the central starting point of that article. using *optimal* `isPrime` function makes the overall code "half-quadratic" (about n^1.5) and much much faster than this sieve. also, using that link to describe that code can still be misleading: it is a sieve, yes, but not of Eratosthenes. :) (I've edited, hope it's OK)

Answer (score 5):

The core of your solution attempt is the infinite list of `primes` given by:

```
primes = 2:(tail primes)
  ++ [head [x | x <- [3,4..]
              , k <- primes
              , ifDoesn'tDivide x k == True]]
```

*Update:*  You mentioned in a comment that you were thinking of this algorithm imperatively, so you were imagining that Haskell would use a "current" value of `tail primes` that was still empty in order to evaluate something like `[2] ++ [] ++ [3]` and then loop.  But, of course, Haskell isn't imperative and so doesn't work like this.  In Haskell, `primes` has one, fixed definition that stays the same throughout the execution of the program.  A Haskell program can "discover" (or more accurately "compute") the definition gradually, which allows us to define `primes` in terms of itself in the first place, but it can't change the definition over the course of execution.

So, in looking at this definition, you need to imagine that `primes` and consequently `tail primes` have the same value everywhere they appear, even when being used recursively.  This is different than a typical recursive function that takes an argument:

```
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n-1)
```

Here, even though the *function* `fact` has the same definition everywhere it appears, the value of `fact n` on the left-hand side and the value of `fact (n-1)` on the right-hand side can be different, thanks to the different argument.

Anyway, if we look at this `primes` definition with the idea that we need `primes` to be the infinite list of all primes **everywhere it appears** (and not with a value that changes or "grows" over time), then you can see why this definition won't work.  Here, `primes` is defined as `2 : tail primes ++ [expr]` for a complicated `expr` that does all the real work, but `tail primes` is supposed to be infinite, so in evaluating this expression you'll never even *get* to `expr`, because you'll never exhaust the list `tail primes`.

Even ignoring the `++ [expr]` bit, because `primes` has a single fixed definition, an expression like:

```
primes = 2 : tail primes
```

isn't the right way to define an infinite list in terms of itself.  The problem is that the second element of `primes` is defined to be the first element of `tail primes`, which is the second element of `primes`, so the second element of `primes` is defined as itself.  That will create an infinite loop when Haskell tries to "discover"/"compute" its value.  The key to the `fibs` definition:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

is that the first and second elements are given, and then the third element is defined as the sum of the first two elements -- it isn't defined in terms of itself, but rather, it's defined in terms of earlier list elements.  That's the key to a successful recursive definition of an infinite (or even finite) list.

Note that Haskell doesn't "know" that `fib` is an infinite list and doesn't do anything special for infinite lists.  This would work the same way with recursively defined finite lists:

```
countdown = 10 : takeWhile (> 0) (map (subtract 1) countdown)
```

The key again is that each element in `countdown` is defined in such a way that it depends only on the *previous* element of `countdown`.

To modify your `primes` definition to work this way, what you probably want to do is generalize your list comprehension from getting the next prime after "2" to get the "next" prime after any current prime `p`, based on having `primes` available:

```
primeAfter p = head [x | x <- [p+1..], k <- primes, ifDoesn'tDivide x k]
```

This won't work for two reasons.  First, because `primes` is infinite, this will keep checking divisibility by different `k` values forever.  We need to modify it to check primes `k` only up to the current prime `p`:

```
primeAfter p = head [x | x <- [p+1..]
                       , k <- takeUntil (==p) primes
                       , ifDoesn'tDivide x k]
```

This uses a helper that takes the beginning of a list up until the first element where a predicate is true:

```
takeUntil p lst = case break p lst of (a,y:b) -> a ++ [y]
```

Second, the check is structured incorrectly.  This list comprehension will allow through an `x` if there's *any* prime `k` that doesn't divide it.  We need to let through an `x` only if *all* primes `k` don't divide it:

```
primeAfter p = head [x | x <- [p+1..]
                       , and [ifDoesn'tDivide x k
                               | k <- takeWhile (<=p) primes]]
```

then it has a chance of working, and we can define `primes` as:

```
primes = go 2
  where go p = p : go (primeAfter p)
```

Here, `go` adds the current prime to the list and then recurses to the next prime, using `primeAfter`.  This works because even though `primeAfter p` accesses the infinite list `primes` being generated by the recursive `go` call, it only uses that list *up to* the current prime `p`, so it stops just before trying to access its own value in the list, only using primes generated *before* the call the `primeAfter p`.

So, this works, and I think is much in the spirit of your original attempt:

```
-- note this simplified version:
ifDoesn'tDivide :: Int -> Int -> Bool
ifDoesn'tDivide n k = mod n k /= 0

primes :: [Int]
primes = go 2
  where go p = p : go (primeAfter p)

primeAfter :: Int -> Int
primeAfter p = head [x | x <- [p+1..]
                       , and [ifDoesn'tDivide x k
                               | k <- takeUntil (==p) primes]]

takeUntil :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeUntil p lst = case break p lst of (a,y:b) -> a ++ [y]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ take 10 primes
```

As @Mihalis has pointed out, `primes` is a pretty standard example in Haskell, so there are more elegant, one-line solutions to this, too.

Comment: So, this definition of the Fibonacchi sequence is realization of generating function concept and this approach is suitable here because the origin of Fibonacchi sequence is recursive? You've clearified that alghorithm I used creates an infinite loop, thus we won't evaluate even 2nd prime number. How does Haskell understand that my data stracture supposed to be infinite (like, because of lentgh primes  equal length primes + 1?). Because, iI still think of this alghorithm in imperative way, and I thought that first step would be like this:
```primes = [2] ++ [ ] ++ [3]```

Comment: @FoxZ322 Haskell _doesn't_ know that the calculation is infinite. In fact, Haskell _can't_ know that (it's the unsolvable Halting Problem). So it just goes into an infinite loop trying to generate the second element until it fills up its allotted memory and throws the stack overflow error as you observed.

Comment: @FoxZ322, I tried adding some explanation to address your comment.

Answer (score 2):

*TL;DR:* no, the two algorithms are not substantially different.

---

Your definition, `primes = 2:(tail primes) ++ ....` says that `head primes = 2` and `head (tail primes) = head ((tail primes) ++ ....) = head (tail primes)`. And that's of course problematic, causes infinite recursion.

---

The smallest fix to your code while preserving its intent is probably

```
firstPrimes1 :: Int -> [Int]
firstPrimes1 1  = [2]
firstPrimes1 n  = firstPrimes1 (n-1) ++ 
         take 1 [x | x <- [3,4..], 
                     and [ mod x k > 0 | k <- firstPrimes1 (n-1)]]
```

(this uses `take 1 ...` in place of your `[head ...]`).

It is unbelievably slow ([looks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) exponential, or worse). But it should have been, of course,

```
firstPrimes2 1  = [2]
firstPrimes2 n  = let { ps = firstPrimes2 (n-1) } in
       ps ++ 
         take 1 [x | x <- [3,4..], 
                     and [ mod x k > 0 | k <- ps]]
```

which is now simply very slow, about cubic in time complexity. But it should have *really* been this, though:

```
firstPrimes2b 2  = [2]
firstPrimes2b n  = let { ps = firstPrimes2b (n-1) } in
       ps ++ 
         take 1 [x | x <- [last ps+1..], 
                     and [ mod x k > 0 | k <- ps]]
```

which now [behaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) as if *quadratic*, and indeed is yet much faster than its predecessor in concrete terms as well.

To structure it like the Fibonacci stream, it could be written as

```
primes3 = 2 : concatMap foo [1..]
  where
  foo k = let { ps = take k primes3 } in
          take 1 [ x | x <- [last ps+1..], 
                       and [ mod x k > 0 | k <- ps]]
-- or 
primes4 = 2 : concatMap bar (tail (inits primes4))
  where
  bar ps = take 1 [ x | x <- [last ps+1..], 
                        and [ mod x k > 0 | k <- ps]]
-- or even 
primes5 = 2 : [p | (ps, q) <- zip (tail (inits primes5)) primes5
                 , p <- take 1 [ x | x <- [q+1..], 
                                     and [ mod x k > 0 | k <- ps]]]
```

Indeed it looks like it follows an inductive pattern, specifically that of *complete* aka *"strong"* induction, `forall(n).(forall( k < n ).P(k)) => P(n)`.

So it is *not* fundamentally different from the Fibonacci calculation, although the latter refers only to the previous two elements whereas this one refers to *all* the previous elements while adding the new one. But just as the Fibonacci stream, this sequence too is defined ultimately in terms of itself: `primes = ..... primes ......`.

The `inits` makes `bar` refer to the previously known primes `ps` explicitly while adding *one more* to them at each step (*expressed by `take 1`*), just like you wanted. `concatMap` collects all the new one-element segments produced by each invocation of `bar`.

But why should that be only *one* prime? Couldn't we safely produce *more* than one new prime, from the `k` known previous primes? Must we really test the  candidates  by all the preceding primes, or can we use the well-known shortcut which you also mention in the question? Can we make it follow the pattern of complete *prefix* induction, `forall(n).(forall( k < floor(sqrt(n)) ).P(k)) => P(n)`, so that only *O(log log n)* expansion steps are needed to get to the *n*th prime?

Could we be producing *longer* segments on each step from each prefix of the primes sequence (which sequence always stays the same, of course), thus referring not to all the preceding primes for each candidate, but only to a much smaller portion of them?...

---

True sieve of Eratosthenes' most direct expression in Haskell is

```
import qualified Data.List.Ordered as O (minus)

primes = map head $ scanl (O.minus) [2..] [[p,p+p..] | p <- primes]
```

(With its obvious semantics, [`minus`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:minus) is easy to implement yourself, if not load from the [data-ordlist](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist) package.)

Although Rev. S. Horsley, when he (re?-)introduced it in 1772,<sup>(*)</sup> described the sieve of Eratosthenes as the equivalent of

```
oprimes = map head $ 
       scanl (O.minus . tail) [3,5..] [[p*p,p*p+2*p..] | p <- oprimes]

primes2 = 2 : oprimes

primesUpTo n = 2 : map head a ++ takeWhile (<= n) b
   where
   (a,b:_) = span ((<= n) . (^2) . head) $
       scanl (O.minus . tail) [3,5..] [[p*p,p*p+2*p..] | p <- oprimes]
```

Running `length $ primesUpTo n` is immensely faster than `length . takeWhile (<= n) primes`. Can you see why?

Can you fix `primes2` so it becomes as fast as `primesUpTo`, in accessing its  `n`th element? It can follow your original thought, extending the known segment of primes, step by step, as alluded to in the previous section.

Also, do note that no `isPrime` function is used here at all. Which is the hallmark of the *true* sieve of Eratosthenes, which does not test for primality, it *generates* the composites, and gets the primes between the composites, for free.

---

How the first `scanl` code works: it starts with the sequence  `[2,3,4,5,...]`. Then it makes a notice to remove `[2,4,6,8,...]` from it, and is left with the equivalent of `[3,5,7,9,...]` i.e. *coprimes({2})*.

<sup>(This works, even though the lists are infinite, because Haskell has lazy evaluation -- only as much calculations are performed as demanded by the needs of performing the final output of the program.)</sup>

Then it makes a notice to remove from *them* the list `[3,6,9,12,..]`, and is left with *coprimes({2,3})*.

At each stage it takes the `head` off the *sequence-at-that-point-in-time*, and puts that head element aside, thus forming the resulting sequence of primes.

<sup>(The same could be coded with `iterate` (or `unfoldr`, etc.). It's a nice exercise, can help clarify what's going on there exactly. When you'll do this, you'll see you'll be re-creating the primes sequence as part of the arguments to the *step* function being iterated (the current sequence of the first *k* primes' coprimes, and the next, *k+1*-th prime, to remove *its* multiples from that sequence). The `scanl` versions refer to the *original* sequence of primes explicitly, taking the primes from it one after another, but it's the same thing.)</sup>

The second `scanl` variant only enumerates the prime's *odd* multiples, starting each enumeration from the prime's square (so, for e.g. *3* it's `[9,15,21,27,...]`, and for *7* it's `[49,63,77,91,...]`). It still starts that enumeration for each prime though, not for each prime's square; that's why it has to make special arrangements to stop as soon as it's okay for it to stop, in the `primesUpTo` function. Which is the key to [*its* efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891%20%5Bprimes%5D%20postpone).

---

<sup>(*)</sup> [pg 314 of Philosophical Transactions, Vol.XIII.](https://books.google.com/books?id=YvZbAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA314&dq=Horsley%201772%20sieve%20little%20labour&hl=en)

---

see also: `minus` defined and used [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Initial_definition), or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_features#Hamming_numbers).

Comment: I still have some questions:
`primes = map head $ scanl (O.minus) [2..] [[p,p+p..] | p <- primes]`
as @K. A. Buhr mentioned, in Haskell primes sequence must have same value everywhere it appear, so it shouldn't work (and it doesn't work, at least in my case). But i have question on that `(minus) [2..] [p, p+p..]` for any p: we are crossing off all multiples of p, but list [2..] is infinite. I still think it is what was called unfaithful sieve of Eratosthenes' in the The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes article @Mihalis mentioned. Also both `primes` and `primesUpTo n` doesn't compute for n > 5.

Comment: I've tested all the variants I posted. here's a copy-paste from my GHCi session: https://pastebin.com/j9NJx8nb. it works. how are you testing it? -- the "unfaithful" is what that user posted. it uses `rem` for each candidate. my code *calculates* the composites by counting up in constant increments; not *tests* for them.

Comment: @FoxZ322 if something is unclear, don't hesitate to ask. :)